# Will SQL Server 2012 Express Management Studio work well with SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, management-studio-express

Can I use SQL Server 2012 Express by installing Management Studio of Standard Edition 2012?

I installed SQL Server 2012 Standard edition, now I have setup of Express 2012 Management Studio.

If I will download management studio once more for standard edition it will take a few more hours and time will be wasted if I can use Express edition Management Studio with standard edition SQL Server.

I want to save time so want to know compatibility or any other issue.

Kindly respond ASAP.

Comment: The "normal" Management Studio that comes with SQL Server 2012 works just fine against **any** edition including Express

Comment: "normal" Management Studio? Do you mean standard edition?
Any link of "normal" Management Studio?